# How to transfer the code from application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know that by default, views in Rails use the template provided in application.html.erb
It's my default template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ... any code ...
</head>
<body>
 <header> ... any code ... </header>

  <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**I need to transfer the code header> in partial template.**

This is my attempt:

1. I created in section view/layouts/header_menu.html.erb
2. I added methode in helpers/application_helper.rb

   def layout_header

   ```
   render 'layouts/header_menu'
   ```

   end

And called it in application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ... any code ...
</head>
<body>

  <%= layout_header %>

  <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**It is my Error:**
*Missing partial layouts/header_menu with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "E:/BDR_SEVERNEFT/app/views"*

I used Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

You can render partials directly in the .erb file using `<%= render layout/header_menu %>` and the partial file needs to start with an underscore i.e. "_header_menu.html.erb".

If you want to use your method call approach, call `render partial: "layout/header_menu"` and again, make the file name "_header_menu.html.erb".

Comment: Thanks! A big help to me. Work both ways!